# Hierarchy for Google maps and OpenStreetMaps

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps

i am wondering about the hierarchy that have been used inside the Google maps and open street maps.. what kind of hierarchy was impeded inside of them ??? if a curious man like me would like to explore and read more about them, where he can find the right source to do that ??

secondly, 
About the entities that are dynamically presented inside the same above mentioned programs, what was the mechanism of decision-making that led to show the presented entities in every scale level, for instant why would in this particular level of detail a labeling for a church while there are other entities that weren't shown at the same level .
i know they are related to the generalization algorithm inside of those programs, but how we can read more about them .

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please try to summarize what exactly you are asking for in 1..2 sentences.

Comment: Quote: "i know they are related to the generalization algorithm inside of those programs, but how we can read more about them" I think you are heavily over-estimating the level of automation here. Working on an OSM Renderer for ArcGIS myself, and having seen the work done on the OSM Carto style, I know most of these decisions are made by humans (cartographers) instead of automation, by manually defining the rules in styles. I am pretty sure Google Maps isn't any different. Have a look at the Github repository of OSM Carto for more info: https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto

Answer (score 2):

In OpenStreetMap, stylesheets, styling, or rules are terms generally to describe the determines what features (Roads or no roads? If yes, which ones?) are drawn at a particular zoom level and how (is a road black? with or without the road's name?).

The stylesheet/rules reads each feature's tags.

The rendering software (usually its mapnik) will read the styling rules to draw the lines and icons on a map.

This is a very simplified version of this process.